# Python: Is there a way to provide a type annotation for a generic list of an arbitrary number of dimensions?

Tags: python, mypy, python-typing

I've been trying to add type annotations to some code that can generate lists of arbitrary dimension, but where each element is ultimately some genericised type.

More concretely, I have some code like this:

```py
T = TypeVar("T")

def to_list(s: str, cls: Union[Type[T], Callable[[str], T]]) -> list:
   """
   Create an n-dimensional list from ``s``.

   ``s`` is a string representing an n-dimensional list,
   where elements are separated with commas, and lists are
   encapsulated with curly braces.

   For example: "{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}".

   :param s: The string to be converted to a list.
   :param cls: The function or class constructor to use to
               convert from string to the types required in
               the list.

   :return: The created list.
   """
```

So calling `to_list("{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}", int)` returns `[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]`.

Is there a way to be more specific about the return type than having to use `list`?

The return value is an n-dimensional list where every non-list element is of type `T`.

Is there a way of typing that?

Sort of similar to how `tuple[T, ...]` indicates a `tuple` of `T` elements of any length, I want a `list` of `T` elements of any "depth".

The following don't work:

- `list[T, ...]`
- `list[..., list[T]]`

---

Edit: The similar question answered this for me.

You can do:

```py
T = TypeVar("T")
TS = Union[T, list["TS"]]

def to_list(s: str, cls: Union[Type[T], Callable[[str], T]]) -> TS:
```